# Is it called a section?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about what you call a section that is denoted with ":". Just simply what you call that in javascript? Do you use the word section or do you call it something else?
The code I am wondering about is the "preferences:" part, just what do you call a section like that?

```
  for(let a = 0; a < this.ingredients.length; a += 1) {
    if (this.ingredients[a].category === this.currentCategory) {
      preferences: {
        if(this.iNeedLactoseFree == true && this.ingredients[a].milk_free == 0) {
          break preferences;
        }
        if(this.iNeedGlutenFree == true && this.ingredients[a].gluten_free == 0){
          break preferences;
        }
        if(this.iNeedVegan == true && this.ingredients[a].vegan == 0){
          break preferences;
        }
        ing.push(this.ingredients[a]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: We need a [mre].  I guess this snippet is inside an object literal.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: The line `preferences:` looks like a "label", linked by 04FS.

Comment: @Keith Maybe, but it isn't constructive or helpful to tell someone their code is bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I approached this question by first confirming that this usage of `break` is valid. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break):

> The break statement includes an optional label that allows the program to break out of a labeled statement. The break statement needs to be nested within the referenced label. The labeled statement can be any block statement; it does not have to be preceded by a loop statement.

Here is the page on block statements: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

> A block statement (or compound statement in other languages) is used to group zero or more statements. The block is delimited by a pair of curly brackets and may optionally be labelled:

So it is called a **labeled block statement** or simply "labeled statement" and you may call `preferences` itself a label.